# How to get current xml file name in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am transforming one XML to html and using `document-uri()` to get current filename. This code is working fine when i am transforming on my local system but with java when i try to transform on server and application it is not returning any value.

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(replace(document-uri(.), '.*/', '') , '.xml')"/>
```

Comment: This seems to be more of a Java problem than an XSLT problem. I tested it with Saxon-9 and it works as desired. So I added the Java tag.

Comment: The issue seems to be more with the relative/absolute path of the XML file. The XML file may be working in local as it could have been placed in the classpath, however when deployed on the server, the XML file may not be available at the classpath and hence `null` is being returned. Please check on the file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If document-uri(.) returns nothing, this suggests that the URI where the document is stored is unknown. This probably means that the document was in memory when passed to the XSLT processor, for example:

- you may have passed a `StreamSource` with no system ID property
- you may have passed a DOM Document

So we need to see how the XSLT transformation was invoked.

Comment: Yes!! you are right we did that the same. I Just see this with the java team now they got this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(base-uri(.), '/')[last()]"/>
```

Comment: Even document-uri(.) is not returning anything if i try to print complete document-uri(.) locally it is fine but we are calling this XSL file for transformation its returning nothing.